# zipped datasets do not work with interleave

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

My `parse_fn` takes in two arguments after `self`:

```
def _parse_fn(self, filename, example_proto):
    ...
    labels["filename"] =filename`
    ...
```

The goal is to return labels that include the tfrecord filename.

I use `Dataset.zip` to concatenate the filenames to the contents of the tfrecords.
The deprecated tf 1.x call with `parallel_interleave` nests well with `Dataset.zip` and multiple (2) inputs for my `_parse_fn`.

In contrast, the new api call `dataset.interleave` does not allow the use of `Dataset.zip` to send multiple inputs to `parse_fn`.

```
def _load_records_with_filenames(filename):
    if self._multi_crop_count is not None:
        filename = tf.stack(self._multi_crop_count * [filename], axis=0)
    return tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(filename).repeat(None),
                                tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, buffer_size=100 * 1000)))
if old_working_code:
  dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(_load_records_with_filenames, sloppy=True, cycle_length=16)
)
else: # new api does not support nesting with Dataset.zip
  dataset.interleave(map_func=_load_records_with_filenames, cycle_length=16, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

When the new api code (`dataset.interleave`) is run: I get:
`TypeError: _parse_fn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'example_proto'`
This indicates that only one argument is being passed in to _parse_fn despite the `Dataset.zip` call.

Comment: Nice question! Maybe I'll add a bounty if it doesn't get an answer for much longer.